# ButterKnife ViewBinder classes get discarded when using Jack

Tags: android, butterknife

I'm using ButterKnife with Jack (Android build tools version 24.0.3) and the ViewBinder classes get discarded at some point during the build. As a result, the views can't be bound by ButterKnife, because it is unable to find the ViewBinder classes in ButterKnife.findBindingConstructorForClass.

My `build.gradle` file contains the dependencies necessary when using Jack:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}
```

The directory `app/build/intermediates/classes` contains the ViewBinder class, but `app/build/intermediates/packaged/debug/classes.zip` doesn't.

Is this a build configuration issue or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow a "Clean and Rerun" in Android Studio did not clean the build output. After a manual clean, the classes were compiled correctly.

**edit:** this is only a temporary fix, since in subsequent rebuilds without prior clean Jack won't create the ViewBinder classes in jayce format.